# Why root time calculated based on time zone, but other users based on UTC

Tags: time, ntp

i have a strange problem in time configuration. i set time zone Asia/Tehran by  "ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tehran  /etc/localtime"  in my rhel6 server. time is ok in root user but it is different in other users. in other users show time acording UTC. i change time by "zic asia" and "zic -l Asia/Tehran" too but problem persist.thanks inadvance

#date
Sun Feb 26 08:52:39 +0330 2023

$date
Sun Feb 26 05:23:15  UTC 2023

Comment: I don’t see the programming problem here. Perhaps this Question belongs on the sister site for Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

#chmod 0644 /etc/localtime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).